# Problem with Unity C# - The name does not exists in the current context (CS0103)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to the coding world, and I was practicing trying to remake flappy bird game as best as I can.
In the Visual Effects coding it says that it has encountered 0 errors, but when I try to open the script in unity it gives me some errors:

```
(48,13): error CS0103: The name 'pipe' does not exists in the current context
(49,13): error CS0103: The name 'pipe' does not exists in the current context
(52,13): error CS0103: The name 'pipe' does not exists in the current context
(53,29): error CS0103: The name 'pipe' does not exists in the current context
(54,13): error CS0103: The name 'i' does not exists in the current context
(132,16): error CS0103: The name 'pipeHeadTransform' does not exists in the current context
(137,17): error CS0103: The name 'pipeHeadTransform' does not exists in the current context
(138,17): error CS0103: The name 'pipeBodyTransform' does not exists in the current context
```

I tried to change the code, but nothing changed and to be honest I dont know what's wrong, can someone please tell me where is the error? Thanks in advance and sorry for my inexperience.

Here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Level : MonoBehaviour
{

    private const float CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE = 50f;
    private const float PIPE_WIDTH = 7.8f;
    private const float PIPE_HEAD_HEIGHT = 3.75f;
    private const float PIPE_MOVE_SPEED = 3f;
    private const float PIPE_DESTROY_X_POSITION = -100f;

    private List<Pipe> pipeList;

    private void Awake()
    {
        pipeList = new List<Pipe>();
    }



    private void Start()
    {

        //CreatePipe(40f, 20f, true);
        //CreatePipe(40f, 20f, false);
        CreateGapPipes(50f, 20f, 20f);
    }



    private void Update ()
    {
        HandlePipeMovement();

    }



    private void HandlePipeMovement()
    {
        for (int i =0; i <pipeList.Count; i++)
        {
            Pipe pipe = pipeList[i];
        }

            pipe.Move();
        if (pipe.GetXPosition() < PIPE_DESTROY_X_POSITION) 
        {
            //Destroy pipe
            pipe.DestroySelf();
            pipeList.Remove(pipe);
            i-- ;
        }
    }



    private void CreateGapPipes(float gapY, float gapSize, float xPosition)
    {
        CreatePipe(gapY - gapSize * .5f, xPosition, true);
        CreatePipe(CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE * 2f - gapY - gapSize * .5f, xPosition, false);
    }



   private void CreatePipe(float height, float xPosition, bool createBottom)
    {
        //Set up pipe Head
        Transform pipeHead = Instantiate(GameAssets.GetInstance().pfPipeHead);
        float pipeHeadYPosition;
        if (createBottom)
        {
            pipeHeadYPosition = -CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE + height - PIPE_HEAD_HEIGHT * .5f;
        }
        else
        {
            pipeHeadYPosition = +CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE - height + PIPE_HEAD_HEIGHT * .5f;
        }
        pipeHead.position = new Vector3(xPosition, pipeHeadYPosition );


        //Set up pipe Body
        Transform pipeBody = Instantiate(GameAssets.GetInstance().pfPipeBody);
        float pipeBodyYPosition;
        if (createBottom)
        {
            pipeBodyYPosition = -CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE;
        }
        else
        {
            pipeBodyYPosition = +CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE;
            pipeBody.localScale = new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
        }
        pipeBody.position = new Vector3(xPosition, pipeBodyYPosition);


        SpriteRenderer pipeBodySpriteRenderer = pipeBody.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        pipeBodySpriteRenderer.size = new Vector2(PIPE_WIDTH, height);

        BoxCollider2D pipeBodyBoxCollider = pipeBody.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        pipeBodyBoxCollider.size = new Vector2(PIPE_WIDTH, height);
        pipeBodyBoxCollider.offset = new Vector2(0f, height * .5f);

        Pipe pipe = new Pipe(pipeHead, pipeBody);
        pipeList.Add(pipe);
    }


    private class Pipe
    {
        private Transform pipeHeadTransform;
        private Transform pipeBodyTransform;

        public Pipe(Transform pipeHeadTransform, Transform pipeBodyTransform)
        {
            this.pipeHeadTransform = pipeHeadTransform;
            this.pipeBodyTransform = pipeBodyTransform;
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            pipeHeadTransform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * PIPE_MOVE_SPEED * Time.deltaTime;
            pipeBodyTransform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * PIPE_MOVE_SPEED * Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }

    public float GetXPosition()
    {
        return pipeHeadTransform.position.x;
    }

    public void DestroySelf ()
    {
        Destroy(pipeHeadTransform.gameObject);
        Destroy(pipeBodyTransform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have pipe defined in for loop and you are trying to access it outside of it. You should move the curly brace `}` from after `Pipe pipe  ......` to after `i--;`

Comment: } at line 128 should go to line 140, and } at line 46 should go to line 56. its a format issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a formatting issue, I have corrected it and the code is given below; only issue/error I am getting is for `GameAssets`, I am assuming you are trying to access another script named `GameAssets`, but otherwise the formatting errors have been resolved. The problems were with formatting of Curly brackets; the curly brackets were closed before the private variables were called outside the function. This was the reason that the functions `GetXPosition()`and `DestroySelf()` were throwing an error since they were outside the required {}.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Level : MonoBehaviour
{

    private const float CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE = 50f;
    private const float PIPE_WIDTH = 7.8f;
    private const float PIPE_HEAD_HEIGHT = 3.75f;
    private const float PIPE_MOVE_SPEED = 3f;
    private const float PIPE_DESTROY_X_POSITION = -100f;

    private List<Pipe> pipeList;

    private void Awake()
    {
        pipeList = new List<Pipe>();
    }



    private void Start()
    {

        //CreatePipe(40f, 20f, true);
        //CreatePipe(40f, 20f, false);
        CreateGapPipes(50f, 20f, 20f);
    }



    private void Update()
    {
        HandlePipeMovement();

    }



    private void HandlePipeMovement()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pipeList.Count; i++)
        {
            Pipe pipe = pipeList[i];


            pipe.Move();
            if (pipe.GetXPosition() < PIPE_DESTROY_X_POSITION)
            {
                //Destroy pipe
                pipe.DestroySelf();
                pipeList.Remove(pipe);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }



    private void CreateGapPipes(float gapY, float gapSize, float xPosition)
    {
        CreatePipe(gapY - gapSize * .5f, xPosition, true);
        CreatePipe(CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE * 2f - gapY - gapSize * .5f, xPosition, false);
    }



    private void CreatePipe(float height, float xPosition, bool createBottom)
    {
        //Set up pipe Head
        Transform pipeHead = Instantiate(GameAssets.GetInstance().pfPipeHead);
        float pipeHeadYPosition;
        if (createBottom)
        {
            pipeHeadYPosition = -CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE + height - PIPE_HEAD_HEIGHT * .5f;
        }
        else
        {
            pipeHeadYPosition = +CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE - height + PIPE_HEAD_HEIGHT * .5f;
        }
        pipeHead.position = new Vector3(xPosition, pipeHeadYPosition);


        //Set up pipe Body
        Transform pipeBody = Instantiate(GameAssets.GetInstance().pfPipeBody);
        float pipeBodyYPosition;
        if (createBottom)
        {
            pipeBodyYPosition = -CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE;
        }
        else
        {
            pipeBodyYPosition = +CAMERA_ORTHO_SIZE;
            pipeBody.localScale = new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
        }
        pipeBody.position = new Vector3(xPosition, pipeBodyYPosition);


        SpriteRenderer pipeBodySpriteRenderer = pipeBody.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        pipeBodySpriteRenderer.size = new Vector2(PIPE_WIDTH, height);

        BoxCollider2D pipeBodyBoxCollider = pipeBody.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        pipeBodyBoxCollider.size = new Vector2(PIPE_WIDTH, height);
        pipeBodyBoxCollider.offset = new Vector2(0f, height * .5f);

        Pipe pipe = new Pipe(pipeHead, pipeBody);
        pipeList.Add(pipe);
    }


    private class Pipe
    {
        private Transform pipeHeadTransform;
        private Transform pipeBodyTransform;

        public Pipe(Transform pipeHeadTransform, Transform pipeBodyTransform)
        {
            this.pipeHeadTransform = pipeHeadTransform;
            this.pipeBodyTransform = pipeBodyTransform;
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            pipeHeadTransform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * PIPE_MOVE_SPEED * Time.deltaTime;
            pipeBodyTransform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * PIPE_MOVE_SPEED * Time.deltaTime;
        }



        public float GetXPosition()
        {
            return pipeHeadTransform.position.x;
        }

        public void DestroySelf()
        {
            Destroy(pipeHeadTransform.gameObject);
            Destroy(pipeBodyTransform.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would better help future visitors if it explained what you did when you "corrected it" and/or why the error occurred.